# Why does intellij warn 'The IDE is running low on memory and this might affect performance'?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I am using IntelliJ idea for my development tasks. Usually, I have one window opened for my organization's project which is a multi-module project. I also need to open some windows for test projects. Basically, one or two only usually.

At some times, I have my organizations' multi-module project window and 5-6 other IntelliJ project windows open. I do not get any memory related warning, nor do the IDE hangs. But, at sometimes, the IDE gives the low memory warning and hangs in between mouse clicks when I have only 2,3 windows opened.

[image]

This is my current IDE memory utilization. 519 MB is free but the IDE is already hanging.
I want to know if there is something like internal cache which needs to be cleared so it does not hang because this behavior is pretty random. At times, when I have 5,6 windows opened, it doesn't hang and at times when I have 3, it hangs.

Please note that there is nothing extra load that I am running from my IDE like I have no application running inside the IDE, no processes. I am just using IDE to develop and build my projects.

**My IntelliJ IDEA version:  Ultimate 2020.3**

Comment: Project size and number/type of plugins that are active are usually a much bigger factor than just "number of windows open". I've had projects open that required 2-3 GB on their own and others that are much smaller.

Comment: Same with me. The multi-module project I mentioned is a large project but when I had no warnings, I was working on this project at those times also. Is their any limit to keep for heap size? I have 16GB RAM.

Comment: Tip: Go through the IntelliJ panel listing the many plugins bundled with IntelliJ. A short description of each appears as you click. Disable every unneeded plugin. For example, if you are creating a console or desktop app, you can disable the many web-app related plugins.